# unable to update CLOB using DBCP connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob, apache-commons-dbcp

Am trying to do update a clob column using a connection object that is retrieved using Apache DBCP connection pooling.

Earlier, I've implemented connection pooling using [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html) and it was working fine i.e am able to update CLOB. I switched to DBCP because I was getting *java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded*. I've checked connection, resultSet, preparedStatement objects in all the DAOs. All the *finally* blocks have these cursors closed. Still am facing this error and so decided to switch to DBCP.

But, when I try to update CLOB, with this DBCP connection, the application just hangs at *pstmt.executeUpdate()*.

```
Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        CLOB clob = null;
        String q = "UPDATE REPORT_TABLE SET RPT_FILE = ? WHERE RPT_SEQ_NUM = ?";
        ...
            conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(q);
            clob = getCLOB(xmlReport, conn);
            pstmt.setObject(1, clob);
            pstmt.setString(2, reportSeqNo);

            if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1) {
                logger.logError("Report has been successfully UPDATED");
            }
        ...
```

where getCLOB() method is:

```
private CLOB getCLOB(String xmlData, Connection conn) throws SQLException{
    CLOB tempClob = null;
    try{
        // If the temporary CLOB has not yet been created, create new
        tempClob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn, true, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

        // Open the temporary CLOB in readwrite mode to enable writing
        tempClob.open(CLOB.MODE_READWRITE);
        // Get the output stream to write
        Writer tempClobWriter = tempClob.getCharacterOutputStream();
        // Write the data into the temporary CLOB
        tempClobWriter.write(xmlData);

        // Flush and close the stream
        tempClobWriter.flush();
        tempClobWriter.close();

        // Close the temporary CLOB
        tempClob.close();
    } catch(SQLException sqlexp){
        tempClob.freeTemporary();
        sqlexp.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception exp){
        exp.printStackTrace();
        tempClob.freeTemporary();
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tempClob;
}
```

I've also tried by passing the `((DelegatingConnection) conn).getInnermostDelegate()` connection, but no use.

Also, I tried what [Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7867/mr-shiny-and-new) has suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862355/overcomplicated-oracle-jdbc-blob-handling). This time its hanging while I'm selecting the data.

Am using Oracle 9i and the JDBC Oracle Driver version is above 10(Sorry, couldn't remember exact version now).

Comment: Could you show your getCLOB method (and what datatype is "xmlReport"?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Oracle JDBC driver, you can't use `setClob()`. It won't throw an error but it also won't work. The reason behind this is that the JDBC driver will try to read your Clob stream *inside* the `executeUpdate()`. So you must open the stream before the update, run the update and then close the stream *afterwards*.

Therefore, I always use `select RPT_FILE ... for update`, and then:

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery ();
        rs.next ();

        Clob clob = rs.getClob (1);
        clob.truncate (0);
        clob.setString (1, data);
    }
    finally
    {
        rs = DBUtil.close (rs);
    }
```

You can replace `setString()` with the methods to read/write the CLOB as a stream. That always works and doesn't leak cursors (because of bugs in Oracle's JDBC driver).

But the key is always the same: You must get a CLOB object from Oracle. Never try to create one of them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the `PreparedStatement.setClob` method instead of `setObject` ?

Answer (score 0):

OTN has some [documentation on clob handling in Oracle JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jdbc/clob10g/handlingclobsinoraclejdbc10g.html) that may be helpful.