# Inserting byte[] array as blob in Oracle Database getting ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: java, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I have a java stored procedure that I am trying to insert a byte[] array into an oracle blob field in a table.

I create a prepared statement as follows but it will randomly fail when I execute the prepared statement. I have narrowed down that the issue is coming from the pstmt.setBytes(4,content). The error I get is:

> ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested.

```
private static void insertFile(Connection connOracle, int zipFileId, byte[] data, String filepath, String filename ) throws SQLException {

try {
    String QUERY = "INSERT INTO files(file_id, zip_file_id, filename, file_path, content) VALUES(SEQ_FILE_ID.nextval,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = connOracle.prepareStatement(QUERY);

    pstmt.setInt(1,zipFileId);
    pstmt.setString(2, filename);
    pstmt.setString(3, filepath);
    pstmt.setBytes(4, data);

    System.out.println("INSERTING file_id " + filepath + ", " + filename + " INTO DATABASE");

    pstmt.execute();
    pstmt.close();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());  
}
```

Comment: Does it happen when content is null or an empty string?

Comment: no, if I comment out the 4th param then everything works great.

Comment: Deleted my answer now that the question has been corrected... is `data` non-null?

Comment: I meant: Does it happen when `data` is null or an empty string?

Comment: no it will not happen if data is null, it only happens when there is content in the byte[] array

Comment: Maybe see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862355/overcomplicated-oracle-jdbc-blob-handling

Answer (score 5):

If I recall correctly the Oracle JDBC drivers (at least in the older ones - you didn't tell us which version you are using) don't support `setBytes()` (or `getBytes()`).

In my experience, using `setBinaryStream()` is much more reliable and stable:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
pstmt.setBinaryStream(4, in, data.length);
```

Comment: what would be different on this from using `Blob`?

Comment: @Goodwine: because in my experience `getBlob()` and `setBlob()` are either not implemented or don't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

try with the below code, this should work for you :-

```
Blob blobValue = new SerialBlob(data);
pstmt.setBlob(4, blobValue);
```