# Inserting Multipart file in to Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, multipart

I'm trying to update the files in the Oracle Db with the help of following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String save(@RequestParam MultipartFile files,@PathVariable int personId,) throws IOException {

        byte [] bFile =files.getBytes();
        personService.uploadImageOnId(personId,bFile);
}
```

This is ServiceImpl

```
@Override
public void uploadImageOnId(int personId,byte [] personImage) {
        entityManager.createNamedQuery("Person.uploadImageOnId")
                .setParameter("personId", personId).setParameter("personImage", personImage)
                .executeUpdate();

    }
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@NamedQueries({ 
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.uploadImageOnId", query = "UPDATE Person p SET p.personImage= :personImage WHERE p.personId= :personId" )

})
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Column(name="PERSON_IMAGE")
        @Lob
        private byte[] personImage;

        public byte[] getPersonImage() {
            return personImage;
        }

        public void setPersonImage(byte[] personImage) {
            this.personImage = personImage;
        }
}
```

but am getting following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

please direct where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Which method call with which acutal parameters cause the exception?

Comment: What if you use Byte instead of byte in your Entity ?

Comment: @Smutje .setParameter("personImage", personImage) here it is pointing error

Comment: Well personImage is not an object so that might be it, can you try to use Byte[] ?

Comment: @Pierre getting same error

Comment: @Pierre No, its not null

Answer (score 2):

Refering to [Inserting byte[] array as blob in Oracle Database getting ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794197/inserting-byte-array-as-blob-in-oracle-database-getting-ora-01460-unimplement), I would suggest not to set the byte array as value but  a `ByteArrayInputStream` wrapping your array.

Comment: I tried this on ur suggestion `.setParameter("personImage", new ByteArrayInputStream(personImage))` but am gettin exception

Comment: we cant use setBinaryStream in createNamedquery

Comment: is der any other way of doing this?