# ORA-01460 with mod_owa and OwaDocTable

Tags: oracle, apache, plsql, mod-plsql

I'm playing with Doug McMahon's Apache PL/SQL Gateway Module (https://oss.oracle.com/projects/mod_owa/dist/documentation/modowa.htm) in a test environment. I'm getting the error below while trying to upload a binary file using the OwaDocTable option. Same code works with mod_plsql.

```
SQL ERROR

Error 1460 calling procedure:

  ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

The last SQL statement executed was:

  begin insert into ATEC2_SCHEMA.UPLOADS (NAME, MIME_TYPE, DOC_SIZE, DAD_CHARSET, LAST_UPDATED, CONTENT_TYPE, BLOB_CONTENT) values (:B1, :B2, :B3, :B4, SYSDATE, 'BLOB', empty_blob()) returning BLOB_CONTENT into :B5; end;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting byte\[\] array as blob in Oracle Database getting ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794197/inserting-byte-array-as-blob-in-oracle-database-getting-ora-01460-unimplement) - just saying "possible"...

Comment: The two issues are probably related, but mod_owa is written in C, not in Java, and I was looking for a solution that does not involve a mod_owa code modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to specify that my test environment was an old 32 bit linux system with Apache 2.0. I try to replicate the problem in a more modern 64 bit linux system with Apache 2.2 and the app works there. So problem solved.